# How NSAnimationContext completionHandler work with Swift Language

Tags: swift

i couldn't port this to swift, rest of NSAnimationContext straight forward.

```
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setCompletionHandler:^(void) {
    //doSomething here...
}];
```

in docs it says var `completionHandler: (() -> Void)!` it did not mean anything to me. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`() -> Void` is the signature for a Swift closure that takes no parameters and returns nothing. Use it much like you would an ObjC block:

```
NSAnimationContext.currentContext().completionHandler = {
    // do something here
}
```

Note that since it's declared as a property, you should set it like one -- ObjC getter/setter pairs don't translate to Swift.

Comment: are you sure about that, it throws error 'NSAnimationContext' does not have a member named 'setCompletionHandler'?

Comment: Ah, didn't catch part of the declaration in your post. See edited answer.

Comment: I stuck this 'var completionHandler: (() -> Void)!' and couldn't see it is simple. it worked, thank you.